# Simulink bus selector after add block

Tags: simulink

In simulink, you can name a signal and in bus creator you combine them and in bus selector you can decompose them again. The problem is when you add two set of signals to each other. Then, the output of add must be combined signals.

Now, my problem is how to name them after (1 by 1) Add in the way that I can select them from bus selector again?

[image: Bus selector after add block]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, it doesn't make sense. Once you have added two signals together, you have a third signal, which you will need to (manually) name. You can't use a bus selector block on the output of an add block to retrieve the initial input signals to the add block.